# How to check whether an audio appears in another?

Tags: algorithm, audio, audio-comparison

For example, I have 2 audios, one is A, and another is B. I want to check whether B appears in A(if part of A is similar to B within some threshold), how many times and what are the exact times B appears.
Is there any algorithm? Or some examples have already done the similar thing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, you need to perform a [cross correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_correlation) between the two audio waveforms. If the correlation waveform peaks above a certain threshold value, then you have found a matching pair. This can be achieved in *O*(*n* log(*n*)) time by using techniques based on [fast Fourier transforms](https://github.com/kunalkandekar/vDSPxcorr),

For music content in particular, you can speed things up by using an [acoustic fingerprinting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acoustic_fingerprint) technique. The Wikipedia article lists several open-source solutions.

Comment: Actually, in my example, A is an audio from broadcast and B is an ad audio. And what I want is to count how many times B appears in A. I don't whether the acoustic fingerprinting techniques, such as Echoprint, works.

Comment: They should help to reduce the computational workload. If you're monitoring a radio station, you'll have high-quality audio samples to work from, which will also help. There's an interesting paper about an audio search algorithm here: http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf

Comment: Unless this is to run in very controlled conditions (such as: synchronous sources, no lossy compression in the signal path) this will not be robust.  Furthermore, the likely application of this presumably searching for M audio fragments in signal A, in which case, the computation load scales with M.  This is why feature extraction techniques are likely to be the way to go here.

Comment: What does the feature extraction techniques mean here? Something like acoustic fingerprinting?

Comment: The paper I linked to above describes a very efficient feature extraction method based on constellation maps. It's patented, however, so you won't be able to use it commercially without a license. But unless you want to do things on a massive scale (like simultaneously checking hundreds of stations for thousands of different adverts), a simpler and less efficient feature extraction method would probably work just fine.